# calculate the profit of each transaction?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have following question regarding the screenshot dataset. Can anyone please tell me how to calculate profit.

Thank you

Create a formula to calculate the profit of each transaction. Which client provided the most profits in October?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYYyW.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm almost sounds like you are trying to get someone to answer your homework for you...

Are you trying to calculate col F correctly?
The numbers you currently have there doesnt make too much sense. My understanding is that charge rate minus breakeven rate = profit rate. Not seeing how a loss is possible (unless there are fixed costs that needs to be deducted first).

=(C2-H2)*D2/60

Comment: My apologies man, my background isn't from business. Therefore, I was unable to figure out myself and it not any assignment just doing online training for myself. Though thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: No problem, I was just joking. Good on you for trying to learn yourself some new skills. Did my formula work for you? Is the problem solved?

Comment: If it worked for you, please approve the answer using the check mark so others know it has been solved. Thanks Sam